# Python Subprocess: how can I launch commands sequentially on multiple GPUs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, subprocess

I have a Linux server with N GPUs, where N is a multiple of 2 (2, 4, or 8). I also have a Python file that I want to launch with GPUs via `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. Generally, I will create multiple `tmux` sessions and launch the commands with:

```bash
# Each command below is run in a separate tmux session
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python main.py --var1 1
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python main.py --var1 2
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python main.py --var1 3
```

Managing the sessions is troublesome, so I implement a piece of code that helps me launch these commands sequentially:

```py
import os
import subprocess

commands = [
'python main.py --var1 1', 
'python main.py --var1 2', 
'python main.py --var1 3'
] 
# List of available GPUs
try:
    available_gpus = os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'].split(',')
    available_gpus = [str(gpu_id) for gpu_id in available_gpus]
except KeyError:
    # If the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable is not set, use all GPUs
    available_gpus = [str(x) for x in range(torch.cuda.device_count())]

n_gpus = len(available_gpus)
procs_by_gpu = [None]*n_gpus

# Iterate over the commands and launch them in parallel
while len(commands) > 0:
    for idx, gpu_idx in enumerate(available_gpus):
        proc = procs_by_gpu[idx]
        if (proc is None) or (proc.poll() is not None):
            # Nothing is running on this GPU; launch a command.
            cmd = commands.pop(0)
            new_proc = subprocess.Popen(
                f'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={gpu_idx} {cmd}', shell=True)
            procs_by_gpu[idx] = new_proc
            break
    time.sleep(1)

# Wait for the last few tasks to finish before returning
for p in procs_by_gpu:
    if p is not None:
        p.wait()
```

Explanation:

- The code will first get the list of GPUs available to run
- If a GPU is free, then it will run the command from `commands.pop(0)` on that GPU
- If there is no free GPU, then it will *wait* until one GPU is free, then it will launch the next command on that GPU
- The process runs until no command is left, then finish the program.

**My question**: I want to extend this code, but in case when I want to use *two or more* GPUs for each process, controlled by an Agument Parser `--gpus`, like `--gpus 2`, then use `args.gpus` in the code. Basically, with `tmux` method, it will be as follows:

```bash
# Each command below is run in a separate tmux session
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python main.py --var1 1
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2,3 python main.py --var1 2
```

How should I extend the previous one to handle multiple GPUs for each command? The following cases can occur:

- In the case where there are 4 available GPUs and `args.gpus=4`, but there is only ONE command, the code runs that command on all 4 GPUs, then exits.
- In the case where there are 4 available GPUs and `args.gpus=4`, but there are two or more commands, the code runs commands sequentially on all 4 GPUs, then exits (equivalent to `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 python main.py --var1 1;CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 python main.py --var1 2`
- In the case when there are 4 available GPUs and `args.gpus=2`, but there is only one command, the code runs that command on the first 2 available GPUs, then exits (equivalent to `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 ptyhon main.py --var1 1`.
- In the case when there are 4 available GPUs and `args.gpus=2`, but there are *two or more* commands, the code runs these commands sequentially, each command uses two GPUs, and the next command is launched right after one of the currently running commands finishes (e.g., command #1 and #2 are running, then command #2 finishes, then command #3 launches right after command #2 and uses command #2's GPUs). This one is equivalent to using two `tmux` sessions and specifying two GPUs in each command.